# How can I get the key_name of the entry in Model() on GAE for Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a `Model()` called `Member` and I'm inserting new entries using `Member.get_or_insert(key_name='lipis')` for example.

My question is how can I get a `key_name` that I used to insert a new entry for a specific `member`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do you mean how do you then find that record using the key name, or how do you take an entity and find its key name?

To get that record back out of the datastore, do:

```
myMember = Member.get_by_key_name('lipis')
```

...if you have the member record and want to get its key name, you can then do:

```
keyName = myMember.key().name()
```

Answer (score 4):

You actually use `key().name()`:

```
lipis = Member.get_or_insert(key_name='lipis')
key_name = lipis.key().name()
```

If it was inserted with a `key_name` (and not an `id`), that will return it.